# NIFI:Merging Flowfiles by filename in MergeContent processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I have flowfiles  named  as (1,3,4,5 and  etc) i  use  this  ${filename} attribute   for invoking online  service, then i  got  big response and  split it  line  by line  but  at the  end  i need to  merge  my  flowfiles  based on  their name i think mergecontent  doesn't  work prperly   i use **Correlation atribute name -filename** and  i have also increased minimum and maximum  number of  entries   but  nothing   helped me  here  is my workflow:
[image]

also  there is  several  subject i am  interested in:

1. I think  that  main reason  my  mergecontent  doesn't  work properly is  that  my  file  names  don't  go one  after  another , can this  bean real reason?
2. Can  you reccomend  me any better  solution  for  such task?

Comment: In order to use Correlation Attribute of filename, all your flow files would have to have the same value for filename so that MergeContent could identity flow files with the same filename and merge them together, but you first stated that the flow files are named (1, 3, 4, 5, etc) so its not going to work if they don't have the same name.

Comment: ok i  seems i   didn't make my question clear if  after  splitting  flowfiles  i have  flowfiles  with name  (1,1,3,1,1)  it means  mergecotent  would't  recognize it?

Comment: how can i mange it  in  s  way  that  it  can work  properly?

Comment: should i  use  another  thisn  for  corelaton atribute name  ?

Answer (score 3):

Simple trick, you should be using `filename` as its asking for correlation attribute name instead of `${filename}`

[image]

PS: i guess this answer is 2years late, well you never know whom it will help :P